# How do I use synology domain name for azure

Tags: azure, dns, synology

Hey guys I build second wordpress on azure,but I wanna use synology domain name for azure.

I use dns server try to pair Cname for azure, but it's not working.

The azure said I don't Verify domain ownership.

But I'm already to setting in Nas Dns server

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are setting a DNS record in a local DNS server. Azure checks for domain ownership from public DNS servers, it doesn't check your local DNS server.
You need to go to your DNS registrar (where you registered the domain) and modify the DNS records there.

If that was allowed, you could verify any domain that you don't own, which isn't what we want.

Comment: uh...cause my network management is not well, so ur mean is I can't use synology give me the dns for use azure?

Comment: The Synology NAS is a local device correct? If so, Azure can't see the DNS records you set there.

Comment: yeah true the nas working in my house, So sounds bad I have to buy other dns.